# Troubleshooting unusual Git issue, specifically the -5938 error code?

Tags: git, ssl, centos

I can't seem to interact with our git repositories from one of our servers, I keep getting an odd message when I try it.

As far as I know the server hasn't been updated in any fashion since the last time this particular action was run where it previously worked correctly.

Can't seem to find any information about the error number that is being returned, any ideas?

```
git pull
error: SSL write: error -5938 while accessing https://....
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

Without any more indepth error information i'm stumped.

Its running Centos 6.6 and Git 1.7.1

Comment: see https://serverfault.com/questions/537495/centos-php-curl-nss-error-5938

Comment: Thanks, answer regarding updating Yum worked a treat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it was a Curl issue, I updated Yum and it seems to have fixed the error.

More info can be found here: https://serverfault.com/questions/537495/centos-php-curl-nss-error-5938